# Object is becoming an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

An object is created here:

```
var versionsLegend={}, versionsCounter=1, currentVersionNum=0;
```

Then in a loop the values should be set - either to a zero value `currentVersionNum` depending on condition or to other values with a counter `versionCounter`

The problem is that with the counter it is set as expected, but when the condition is true and it sets the 0 value it turns the object into an Array and wipes out the previous data.

```
for (var i = 0; i < success.data.data.length; i++) {
    if (success.data.data[i][0].Items.selected) {
        $scope.views.series.push(success.data.data[i][0].Items.id);
        versionsLegend = {
            [success.data.data[i][0].Items.id]: currentVersionNum
        };
    } else {
        versionsLegend = {
            [success.data.data[i][0].Items.id]: versionsCounter
        };
        versionsCounter++;
    }
}
```

In the log before this line:

```
versionsLegend={[success.data.data[i][0].Items.id]:currentVersionNum};
```

I get `Object { 12: 1 }` and after `Object [ <9 empty slots>, 0 ]`

I've omitted the unrelated to the problem parts of the code.

Tried to use `.toString()` on the object keys - to no avail.

Comment: How the console prints values is not standardized. Don't worry about it. The value is still an object.

Comment: Has nothing to do with converting it to an array, it has to do with you overriding the variable on every iteration.

Comment: Felix, indeed! It was the console result that left me puzzled and made me make the mistake of overwriting the object. In fact, the resulting array is fine. 
If you create an answer, I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Doing `versionsLegend={...};` sets the value of versionsLegend to a new object.

Use `versionsLegend[key] = value` instead -- that'll set the property on the current versionsLegend object.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course... My mistake, but it was like that before - I was experimenting with options. Changed it back to:
versionsLegend[success.data.data[i][0].MovieScriptsVersions.id]=currentVersionNum;
And
versionsLegend[success.data.data[i][0].MovieScriptsVersions.id]=versionsCounter;

Same problem persists.